# how to extend the intersection of two protocols in swift

Tags: swift

Trying to add helper functions for classes that conform to two different protocols

```
protocol A {
  func doA()
}
protocol B {
  func doB()
}
typealias AnB = A & B

extension AnB {   // causes error can not extend non-nominal type
  func doAnB()
  {
   doA()
   doB()
  }
}
```

Any way around this?

Comment: `protocol AnB: A, B { }`

Comment: If you can add bit more about what you are trying to achieve would be better?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you cannot extend a composite protocol typealias.

```swift
extension A where Self: B {
  func doAnB() {
    doA()
    doB()
  }
}
```